# Images not uploading

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images

I tried to upload images for product but its not uploading and getting an like

> unable to list current working directory

[image]

Comment: Did you set File Permission in Media folder

Comment: Yes, I'm using 777 permission for that folder

Comment: i think it will help your prolem http://importantmagento.blogspot.in/2012/05/magento-error-unable-to-list-current.html

Comment: Sorry it's not working

Comment: Any error in console  or log ?

Comment: I guess you are on a VPS? Check the permissions (should be 755) and the owner of the dir /media and all its subdirs. Check if /media/tmp exists with the correct permissions. Also use only latin charachters for your filenames, preferably without spaces.