# Unable to list current working directory

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

I am unable to upload product images for clothing and jewelry attributes

[image]

Comment: There is also no reason to ask the same question twice. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166194/images-not-uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions on the `media` directory and its subdirectories.  Make sure the user your webserver is running as has permission to read and write to the directories.